# Help with Receiver / Transmitter (nRF24L01+)

Tags: c++, nrf24l01+

Dear fellow Arduino users,

My two friends and I are having trouble on an Arduino project we are working on. We are using two Arduino Uno's and trying to have one of them send a signal to another one by a press of a button using NF24L01+ (with the antenna). Our transmitter code is as follows:

```
// create an RF24 object
RF24 radio(9, 8);  // CE, CSN
```

// the number of the pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin = 3;

// variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonState = 0;

//address through which two modules communicate.
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("nrf24L01+ Transmitter Starting!\n");

// initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);

//set the address
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);

radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);

//Set module as transmitter
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (buttonState == 1) {
    Serial.write("Sending the following message: \n");

```
//Send message to receiver
const char text[] = "\t Hello, friend!";
Serial.write(text);
Serial.write("\n\n");

radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));

delay(1000);
```

}
}

On the receiver side, we have the following:

//create an RF24 object
RF24 radio(9, 8);  // CE, CSN

//address through which two modules communicate.
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();

  //set the address
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);


  //Set module as receiver
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
  //Read the data if available in buffer
  if (radio.available())
  {
    Serial.print("hello");
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}

However, we are not receiving any signal on the receiving end. We are pretty sure all our pins are correct. We are wondering if anyone had any advice on how we could troubleshoot. Thank you.

Comment: you need code running on the receiver end

Comment: You also need to check wiring on both devices.